# Element not having 100% height in drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

trying to create a simple drop down menu but it is for a navigation bar with percentage sizes.

Everything works as it should, but the styling for the title of the drop down isnt working.

I want it to have a 100% height of the navigation bar, and there for when the drop menu appears, it sits directly under the navigation bar.

Currently, the title wont adjust its height so the drop down menu sits directly under the content.

I am also looking to shift the whole drop down menu so it aligns the right hand side with the right hand side of the div.

Here is a fiddle of current:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaMjp/1/

just for show, heres the code:

```
<div id="topbar">
<div id="topbarcentre">
    <div class="pagecontrol1">
        <div id="showbuildfollowers">
            <div class="buildscore">
                <ul class="menu-buildpoints">
                    <li>
                    <a class="buildpointstitle" href="#">
                        <div class="buildscoretext">3.2k</div>
                    </a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Views: 1372</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Followers: 89</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Comments: 102</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
* {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;text-decoration:none;}
#topbar {
height: 6%; 
width: 100%; 
background-color:#444; 
position:fixed; 
z-index: 950;
}

.pagecontrol1 {
color:#FFF;
padding-top: 0%;
height: 100%;
}

#topbarcentre {
width: 82%;
margin:auto;
height: 100%;
}

#showbuildfollowers {
width: 10%;
float:right;
margin-right: 22%;
margin-left: 1px;
padding: 0%;
height: 100%;
}

.buildscore {
width: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #444;
background-color: #666;
color:#fff;
font-size: 12px;
float:left;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 100%;
outline: none;
display: table;
}

.buildscore:hover {
background-color:#555;
cursor: pointer;
 }

.menu-buildpoints {
color: #fff;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
background-color:#999;
 }

.buildpointstitle {
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.buildscoretext {
background-color: #f00;
}

/* DROP IT CSS */

.dropit {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger { position: relative; }
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0; /* dropdown left or right */
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
min-width: 150px;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu { display: block; }

.menu-buildpoints ul {
display:none;
}
.menu-buildpoints ul.dropit-submenu {
background-color:#555;
border:1px solid #444;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.menu-buildpoints ul.dropit-submenu a {
display:block;
font-size:14px;
line-height:25px;
color:#fff;
padding:0 18px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
.menu-buildpoints ul.dropit-submenu a:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

You can see a background of red is given to the title to show clearly its height, once its 100% height, the whole div will be clickable too.

Any help on these issues? Using a jquery snippet called Dropit. All code can be seen on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Just to understand you correctly, upon clicking on 3.2k, the drop down should be just under the navigation bar correct?

If that's the case, here are a couple options you can try:

```
.buildscoretext{
margin:auto;
display:block;
height:100%;
}
```

This should turn the navigation into a block forcing the drop down to be at the correct height.

If this doesn't work, you can also try to add margin-top to the .dropit ul class.

Not to be one of those guys but try to limit your use of divs. With HTML 5, using classes and ID's makes things much simpler. You have several div's before your navigation and the complexity is not necessary. Next time you can try something like:

```
<div id="header-container">
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
```

Hope this helped, if not I'll be happy to try again.

Answer (score 0):

The submenu is `position: absolute` which means it'll position based on the boundary of the parent container (the root `li`). You'll need to give it a fixed `top: x` height that's equal to the nav bar height.

[example](http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/CBvkg)

Answer (score 0):

**block and height**

I fixed it by adding this:

```
.dropit, .dropit-trigger, .dropit-trigger a{display:block}
.dropit, .dropit-trigger, .dropit-trigger a, .dropit-trigger div{height:100%;}
```

and removing this:

```
.menu-buildpoints { display: table-cell }
.buildscore {display: table}
```

[made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/PcaBW/)

`height:100%` is normally relative to the parent, so from the nav through the div inside the anchor, everything should have `height:100%`

Comment: I'm not seeing his desired effect with this? The anchor is just smaller and the submenu is still below it. Firefox 26/Mac

Comment: the display table was a fix to make the buildscoretext div remain centre of the container, how can i make it centre vertically now with your method? many thanks!

Comment: easiest way would be to add padding to the top. Since `display:table-cell` doesn't support % dimensions fully, you would need to rewrite the dimension to have something like `em` `px`, etc. something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/CE6vc/). I reorganized the css a bit to make it easier to see where everything is.

Comment: I've got another idea too, but you would still lose the 6% height for it to work, if I get a chance in the am I'll try it out.

Comment: is there a need for the 6% height to stay?